# Role "postgres" doesn't exist on Windows 7

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-7

When running the following command after `pg_ctl initdb` and `pg_ctl start` commands:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin>psql.exe -U postgres -h localhost
```

I am getting the following error:

```
role "postgres" doesn't exist
```

All similar questions are about Linux or Mac and they don't help me much, so I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify a username with `-U` when you ran `initdb`, the bootstrap superuser has the name of the operating system user with which you ran `initdb`.

So you can simply connect with

```
psql
```

If you would like to change the name of the user to `postgres`, that is simple:

```
-- get the name of the current user in a variable
SELECT current_user \gset
CREATE ROLE dummy SUPERUSER;
-- connect as user "dummy"
\c - dummy
-- rename the bootstrap user to "postgres"
ALTER ROLE :"current_user" RENAME TO postgres;
-- remove "dummy"
\c - postgres
DROP ROLE dummy;
-- disconnect
\q
```